# Sending data through activities using Parcelable is not working

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I need to send  a `ArrayList<String>` to another Activity, so I create this Activity which implements `Parcelable`.

```
public class ParceDataImages implements Parcelable {

private ArrayList<String> Images;

public ParceDataImages(ArrayList<String> images) {
    this.Images = images;
}
public ParceDataImages(Parcel parcel) {
    this.Images = new ArrayList<String>();
    parcel.readList(this.Images,String.class.getClassLoader());
}

public ArrayList<String> getImages() {
    return Images;
}
public void setImages(ArrayList<String> images) {
    Images = images;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(Images);
}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParceDataImages> CREATOR = new ClassLoaderCreator<ParceDataImages>() {
    @Override
    public ParceDataImages createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public ParceDataImages createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ParceDataImages(source);
    }
    @Override
    public ParceDataImages[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParceDataImages[size];
    }
};
```

And inside of my Adapter:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            ParceDataImages parceDataImages = new ParceDataImages(ImageArray);
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity,UserAdsView.class);
            intent.putExtra("data",parceDataImages);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity :

`ParceDataImages parce = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("data");`

And a I got this Exception : `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system`

Comment: Have you seen the `Intent#putStringArrayListExtra()` method?

Comment: I think you should use intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra( parceDataImages ) instead of intent.putExtra

Comment: I did, but it expect a List, and I did parceDataImages.getImages

Comment: There's no need to create a custom `Parcelable` for this. You can already pass an `ArrayList<String>` on an `Intent`. Look at my comment above.

Comment: It's not working : E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2027964)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system

Comment: You're trying to send too much data through an `Intent`. There's a practical limit of one megabyte total on the size of extras.